# python SDK getMoreResults() doesn't retrieve any result

Tags: dataextensions, fuel-sdk, python

I am retrieving some DE rows that for sure have more results. The code:

```
client = FuelSdkClient(clientId) #FuelSdkClient is a def where I am instantiating a client through a specific account
row = ET_Client.ET_DataExtension_Row()
row.auth_stub = client
row.props = fieldsList #defined previously
row.CustomerKey = customerKey #defined previously
row.search_filter = {'Property':'MID', 'SimpleOperator':'equals', 'Value':'123456789'}

#first response
response = row.get()
result = response.results #list of results

#inserting more_results in 'result' list
while response.more_results:
    response = row.getMoreResults()
    result = result + response.results
```

That simple code should work assigning the first response results to the "result" variable and then, while response.more_results equal true, continous concatenating more results to the same "result" variable.

The first call, meaning the get() call, retrieves the first 2500 rows, as expected.

The problem is, when I call getMoreResults, it doesn't retrieve any data and shows an error message as shown below:

```
Error: data extension does not exist: ##data extension name##
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I may have found an answer of what is happening.

In one of my testings, I tried to decrease the lenth of the name of my data extension and then "voilà", it returned me the getMoreResults as expected!

The issue is that for some reason, the getMoreResults method searchs for the name of the data extension even if you set the customerKey as a parameter, like I did in my code above, and for some reason, there is a character limit that the SDK reads, or the API itself...

does anyone have a solution other than to shorten the name of data extensions?